# BackgroundWorker only reporting progress when finished

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a very simple app that loads an excel file with several thousand rows into a DataGridView component.  This table is then scanned for duplicates and various other issues by pressing the Scan button.  I chose to have this intensive task run in a BackgroundWorker so the UI remains responsive and so I can report its progress.  The code for my Scan button simply calls the RunWorkerAsync() method on the background worker component, which then does this :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this, dgvScancodes, dgvErroredScancodes, BgwScanner);
```

This calls another class to do the actual work, passing the scanner as a parameter.  The Scanner class then does this :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in table.Rows)
{
    //Long computations on each row

    worker.ReportProgress(row.Index / table.RowCount * 100);
}
```

The scan executes perfectly fine and produces the expected output but my ProgressBar never updates with the following code on the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged event :

```
private void BgwScanner_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Thinking this could be an issue with the way I calculate the percentage, I replaced my call to ReportProgress and just sent a value of 50 to see what would happen.  The progress bar does update, but only when the entire scan is completed!  No exception is raised and it's behaving like the UI thread is too busy doing other things (which, aside from looping over every row in a table, it is not to the best of my knowledge).  Any idea why I'm seeing this behavior?

******EDIT******

I found my culprit.  I forgot that, during the scan, the table's rows can be updated with a tooltip and a background color.  I commented these 2 lines and sure enough the progress bar works perfectly fine now.  This proves my theory that indeed the UI thread is being overwhelmed.  Is there potentially a way around this?  Some sort of higher priority for the progress bar updates?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say. That said, you should look at the hundreds of other questions on Stack Overflow involving the failure of `ReportProgress()` having its intended effect. I guarantee you that your question is not unique, and that it has already been answered here before. The first thing you should check is make sure you've actually set the `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress` property.

Comment: you are right, i read dozens and ultimately one of them pointed me in the right direction.  See my edit.

Comment: There are also many questions already involving saturating the UI thread with background invocations (as well as the "integer divide" issue you also had). You can read those for more details, but the short version is to simply limit the frequency with which you update the UI. At most, an update once every 100-200 ms is the most a user will find useful, and in many cases updates can occur even less frequently without any loss of usability at all.

Comment: Understood, but in my case I'm not sure how I can achieve this.  The scanning process loops through the table and colors certain cells / adds a tooltip text for rows that are problematic.  The act of updating this table is woven into the scanning process.  I'll see if I can figure out a way around this, any suggestions would certainly help.  Thanks

Comment: _"I'm not sure how I can achieve this"_ -- have you taken a look at how others have already addressed it? _"updating this table is woven into the scanning process"_ -- if the coupling of your data layer to your UI layer is too tight/close, it certainly can make it harder to implement good solutions. Maybe the first thing you need to do is abstract those layers more so that they aren't in fact so tightly woven. In any case, ultimately it will all come down to minimize the number and frequency of transitions from the background thread to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this issue by doing the processing on the underlying DataSource for my tables until the very last minute when it needs to be displayed.  This way there are no UI updates until the table is displayed.  I still need to iterate over the table itself to set the background color and tooltip for certain cells at the end (since you obviously can't do this on the DataSource itself) but that takes a relatively short time compared to the processing that is being done on the DataSource beforehand.  My ProgressBar now works properly.

******EDIT******

You can actually use the DataGridView's CellFormatting event to color cells, no need to iterate over the rows and this has the bonus effect of keeping the tooltip and the background color when re-ordering the table :

```
private void dgvErroredScancodes_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell scancodeCell = dgvErroredScancodes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];

    if (e.Value.Equals((int) ErrorType.DUPLICATE))
    {
        scancodeCell.Style.BackColor = ErrorType.DUPLICATE.BackgroundColor();
        scancodeCell.ToolTipText = ErrorType.DUPLICATE.ErrorMessage();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For integer division the value rounds towards zero to the next nearest integer.
In your case it will always round towards exactly zero before being multiplied by 100, since row.index is presumably between 0 and table.RowCount - 1.

Being totally verbose:

```
row.Index / table.RowCount * 100
```

Could become:

```
(int)(((double)row.Index / (double)table.RowCount) * 100)
```

Comment: That was indeed part of the problem but I found the real reason why the progress only updates at the end.  See my edit.